# run loop for extracting part of a file name and run some commands

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm new in bash scripting. I have some files in different directories and wanted to extract part of the filename or directory name and create a variable with that part and apply this variable on the other command.
My directory and file name follow this pattern:

```
user/Sample_001_002_5/001_002_5_fgdfgh_hgf00.gz
user/Sample_254_128_3/254_128_3_wserer_hgf00.gz
```

May I know how I can setup a variable such as i for them?
    i=001_002_5
    i=254_128_3
I wrote bellow script but i is not recognized in my command:

```
dir=/users/Sample_*

for DIR in $dir

do i= basename ${DIR} | cut -c 8-

R="${DIR}/${i}*.gz"   # Run correctly#

echo $i               # run correctly#

echo $R               # run  correctly#

echo '@RG\tID:MCW\tSM:'${i}'\tPL:Illumina\tPU:'${i}"   ### in this command i is not recognized######

done
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the source of the problem, but the double quote at the end of the problematic line is not matched.

(Furthermore, echo has to take the "-e" argument to take \t as a tab character and not literal, if this is what you want. I know this is not something about $i).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry double quote is not in my code and without this still I have an error. And if I use '@RG\tID:MCW\tSM:'${i}'\tPL:Illumina\tPU:'${i} in another command line but echo still have error.